# .Net Web Api Get Method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, get

I'm Learning .NET Web Api.

So this is the default GET Method

```
// GET: api/UserProfiles/5
[ResponseType(typeof(UserProfile))]
public IHttpActionResult GetUserProfile(int id)
{
    UserProfile userProfile = db.UserProfiles.Find(id);
    if (userProfile == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(userProfile);
}
```

This is my model:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Phone { get; set; }
}
```

How can I make it search by `Name` instead of `ID`. 
From what I understand I need to change `GetUserProfile(int id)` to `GetUserProfile(string name)` and in `WebApiConfig.cs` I need to change from

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

to

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{name}",
            defaults: new { name = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

But it's not working. Any tips on how to do it?

Comment: What is it that doesn't work? How can you tell? Does the server throws an error?

Comment: Are you sure you want to change the default route? Have you considered [attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)?

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not change route. Simply you still use `GetUserProfile(string name)` and the request would be `/api/UserProfiles?name=...`

Comment: But what if OP wants to change the route?: it should work as well. Don't get me wrong; I think it's good to point OP to the alternative, but still, it's not an answer to the original question. This might be important for other use cases.

Comment: This also doesn't answer the question because it uses query syntax, rather than route parameter syntax. It should work like `/api/UserProfiles/{name}`.

Comment: thanks, I got this point. Actualy `/api/UserProfiles/{name}` works well in this case